# vue findIndex not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cart, vuex

here I got an error in the `findIndex()` function

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: state.carts.findIndex is not a function`

cartId has rowId and qty and sizeVal and image

**Methods**

```
    updateCart() {
        this.$store.dispatch('updateCart', this.cartId)
    }
```

**State**

```
state: {
    carts: [],
},
```

Vue Inspect Carts

```
031e0275ef3746070e80d81199bd2580:Object {
    id:1
    name:"T-Shirt"
    options:Object {
        image:"products\July2018\4TXSMgf6eAdrOlaxAMiX.jpg"
    }
    size:"l"
    price:551
    qty:2
    rowId:"031e0275ef3746070e80d81199bd2580"
    subtotal:1102
    tax:115.71
}
```

**mutations**

```
    updateCart(state, rowId) {
        const index = state.carts.findIndex(cart => {cart.rowId == rowId});
        // console.log(index)
            state.carts.splice(index, 1, {
                'qty': cart.qty,
                'size': cart.sizeVal,
            })
    },
```

In my Action is work

**Actions**

```
    updateCart(context, cart) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.patch(`update/cart/${cart.id}` , {
                id: cart.rowId,
                qty: cart.qty,
                size: cart.sizeVal,
                image: cart.image
            })
            .then(response => {
                context.commit('updateCart', response.data)
                resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error)
            })
        })

    },
```

Now where the error I need to update carts in state.carts
need help please guys about it why it gives me the error

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `state.carts` is an object, not an Array.
`findIndex` is an [array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

> The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.

Comment: can you please post text instead of the image. The image is not really crawlable by the google bot.

Comment: I prefer image because it's screenshot of document. It proves that I don't modify any thing.

Comment: A quotation should take care of that, possibly linked by the docs. Mind If I try an edit?

Comment: Please send me a link of stack overflow guideline. If it's correct, I'll update.

Comment: There is no exact guideline which says you can't add images, it's mostly so that people can find posts via search engines. [The guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) do say _Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._ but I guess images are ok

Comment: It's not just for bot crawlers. The text is legible on all devices, also for usability etc.

Comment: Agree! Thank you @Lex, Ayush Gupta

Answer (score 1):

Use a PolyFill as a mixin imported globally in Vue.

```
 const findIndex = (values, expectedValue) => {
    let selectedIndex;
    const valuePresent = values.some((value, index) => {
      selectedIndex = index;
      return value === expectedValue;
    });
    return valuePresent ? selectedIndex : -1;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

findIndex is ES6 array feature, make sure it's supported by your browser, or you should apply polyfill or transpile plugins like babel.js to it.

Comment: test [].findIndex on your browser console, if it's a function, then check state.carts instanceof Array.